# Stand alone smart watch/fitness band with skin temperature sensor

Tags: wearable-technology, measurement-devices

I am looking for a smart watch or fitness band that can I can program to monitor skin temperature and alert me when certain criteria are met. I have the following requirements:

1. Worn on the wrist
2. Programmable
3. Body temperature sensor
4. Does not require a paired smartphone
5. Alert mechanism (e.g. vibration or beeping)

Comment: How should the watch alert you without a paired smartphone? On a builtin display?

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm not too particular about how the alert is issued, but I'll add that to the question